# Foundation 6 Switch Label positioning

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation 6 with switch style checkboxes, and would like the labels to appear to the left of the switch instead of above the switch.  Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/douglastaylor/pen/awQeye?editors=1000#0) showing the below code in action

```
<div class='grid-x'>
  <div class='cell small-3' id='quadDivLiveClient'>
    <div class='cell small-5'>
      <label>Exclude condition1?</label>
    </div>
    <div class='cell small-4 end'>
      <div class='switch tiny'>
        <input id='quadChk1' class='switch-input' type='checkbox' 
checked></input>
        <label class='switch-paddle' for='quadChk1'>
          <span class='show-for-sr'></span>
          <span class='switch-active' aria-hidden='true'>Yes</span>
          <span class='switch-inactive' aria-hidden='true'>No</span>
      </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class='cell small-5'>
      <label>Exclude condition2?</label>
    </div>
    <div class='cell small-4 end'>
      <div class='switch tiny'>
        <input id='quadChk2' class='switch-input' type='checkbox' 
checked></input>
        <label class='switch-paddle' for='quadChk2'>
          <span class='show-for-sr'></span>
          <span class='switch-active' aria-hidden='true'>Yes</span>
          <span class='switch-inactive' aria-hidden='true'>No</span>
      </label>
      </div>
    </div>
<div class='cell small-5'>
      <label>Exclude condition3?</label>
    </div>
    <div class='cell small-4 end'>
      <div class='switch tiny'>
        <input id='quadChk3' class='switch-input' type='checkbox' 
checked></input>
        <label class='switch-paddle' for='quadChk3'>
          <span class='show-for-sr'></span>
          <span class='switch-active' aria-hidden='true'>Yes</span>
          <span class='switch-inactive' aria-hidden='true'>No</span>
      </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this codepen?

https://codepen.io/xanisu/pen/yXZjez

Add this css style:

```
.switch-paddle .switch-active, .switch-paddle .switch-inactive{
  position: absolute;
  left: 52px; 
  color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Viewing that codepen, the labels show above the switches rather than to the side.  Checked this in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: ups, I missunderstood your question, I though you wanted to change the "yes"/"no" label to the side, not the "question" label. Is that ok?

Comment: Apologies.  I can see now that I was inadvertantly ambiguous on that.  

Right, what I'm trying to do is put the question label to the side while leaving the yes/no on the switches themselves.  Then end goal is to have a column of switches, so having the question label (the one explaining the purpose of the switch) to the side would probably look the best.

Sort of like:

    "Do you want this feature?"   (switch:yes/no)
    "Do you want this feature?"   (switch:yes/no)

etc...